# Playwright Automation

Tags: automation, playwright

How to convert pdf to text in playwright automation script?

Uploaded the pdf files in resources in automation script and modified in the homepage and tried to run the script to get the text file .
But i  didn't get the pdf in text format

Comment: You need to share the relevant code along with error to get any meaningful help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4):

I suppose what you want to do is to save pdf text in simple .txt files. If that's the case then.
Playwright does not read pdf files and will not extract any data from it. Playwright doesn't support this type of functionality. Instead what you can do is you can use `pdf2json` library and can save pdf text in json format.

From then on you can save that extracted text in .txt file.

Comment: Thanks, I used this in one of my test validations.